# C# rdlc date switch statement not working

Tags: c#, switch-statement, rdlc

```
=Switch(
    IsNothing(Parameters!additionalDate.Value), " ",
    len(Parameters!additionalDate.Value) <5, " ",
    len(Parameters!additionalDate.Value)>=5, CDate(Parameters!additionalDate.Value).ToShortDateString()
    )
```

This will throw a #Error on the report when there is no date. The date field happens to be 2 blank characters. Why would this give an error as output instead of the " "?

Comment: Is this code sample actually C#, or is it a RDLC language I'm not familiar with? If it's VB.NET, perhaps you could update your tags and title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBScript expressions such as `switch()`, `iif()`, and `choose()` don't short-circuit like they would in C#, so all your expressions in your switch statement will be evaluated, no matter what the value is.

Try to perform your validation earlier in your method/process that loads the report. If that is not possible, you have to check for all possible values/nulls in every one if your checks.

Comment: Do you know how I can prevent the CDate() from running if the value is null or has only 2 spaces?